# How to read Json data using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, express

I am working with Express 3 version of the NodeJs and have a SQL query which fetched the data from the database and then I applied JSON.Stringify and then JSON.PARSE function on the results obtained from the SQL query.

My JSON data looks like something like this. result is something on which I am saving my results.

Output at Console of Node Eclipse:

Database Results: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

result `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

On the Angular side I used the below methods:

```
$scope.myResult = response.jsonParse;

console.log($scope.myResult);
```

I am using the Firebug to see my results and I can see the data on Firebug console as in JSON format:

```
{
  "jsonParse": [{
    "ITEM_CODE": 3,
    "ITEM_NAME": "SONY",
    "ITEM_DESC": " 44 inches",
    "ITEM_PRICE": 170,
    "ITEM_QTY": 4,
    "SELLER_FIRSTNAME": "sagar",
    "SELLER_LASTNAME": "kaw",
    "EMAIL": "sagar.kaw@gmail.com",
    "SELLER_USERNAME": "sagkaw",
    "category": "TV",
    "Group_Name": "Electronics"
  }, {
    "ITEM_CODE": 4,
    "ITEM_NAME": "GIBSON",
    "ITEM_DESC": "ACOUSTIC ",
    "ITEM_PRICE": 110,
    "ITEM_QTY": 6,
    "SELLER_FIRSTNAME": "sagar",
    "SELLER_LASTNAME": "kaw",
    "EMAIL": "sagar.kaw@gmail.com",
    "SELLER_USERNAME": "sagkaw",
    "category": "ENTERTAINMENT",
    "Group_Name": "INSTRUMENTS"
  }, {
    "ITEM_CODE": 5,
    "ITEM_NAME": "Marvel Avenger",
    "ITEM_DESC": "Captain America ",
    "ITEM_PRICE": 110,
    "ITEM_QTY": 6,
    "SELLER_FIRSTNAME": "sagar",
    "SELLER_LASTNAME": "kaw",
    "EMAIL": "sagar.kaw@gmail.com",
    "SELLER_USERNAME": "sagkaw",
    "category": "Kids Toy",
    "Group_Name": "TOYS"
  }]
}
```

I copied the JSON data to myResults:

```
 }).success(function(response){

        $scope.myResult = response.jsonParse;
```

Now I have to get this data print on my HTML where I am using

```
  ng-repeat="result in myResult">


  <p><Strong>Item Name : </Strong>{{result.ITEM_NAME}}</p>

  <p><Strong>Item Description : </Strong>{{result.ITEM_DESC}}</p>
```

But its not printing anything.

But if I do

`{{result}}`  : It prints whole data on the screen.

I have to print the data in differently for different Item code.

Comment: Hi. Can you format your question a little? I believe readability will increase a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: put some code of node.js where you are sending data

Comment: @ArifKhan why would that help?...OP  clearly is receiving data in client and problem is in display. Please don't ask for things that aren't relevant to the problem

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. Are you sure that the `ng-repeat` is inside the scope of controller within the view?

Comment: @maverick I think you are getting data in the form of string rather than json or object

Comment: @ArifKhan highly improbable when using `$http` since it returns parsed data by default

Comment: @charlietfl :: I think ng-repeat is within the scope of the controller... because if I do {{result}} or {{result[0].ITEM_CODE}} it displays the data. Its just {{result.ITEM_CODE}} is not displaying anything.

Comment: something strange going on though that `result[0]` works because that's not what the json you posted looks like

Answer (score -1):

This happens because your `myResult` variable is binded to the whole data returned from your server. Instead of doing this

```
$scope.myResult = response.jsonParse;
```

do

```
$scope.myResult = response.data.jsonParse;
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele for your prompt response but on doing that I am getting this error on Firebug. -----  

 Error: response.data is undefined

Comment: Can You Console.log The response.data

Comment: Sorry, my fault `$scope.myResult = response.jsonParse.jsonParse;` or `ng-repeat="result in myResult.jsonParse"`

Comment: @ShankarShastri there is no `data` property in success callback...only in `then()`

Comment: Thanks For That @charlietfl

Comment: Hi Shankar, console.log(response.data); gives me ----- Undefined on the Firebug

Comment: @maverick as it should because the advice was wrong and this answer is wrong

Comment: Then What does console.log(response) gives

Comment: $scope.myResult = response.jsonParse.jsonParse; or ng-repeat="result in myResult.jsonParse" does not gives me the result ...I am getting undefined on the Firebug console @Gabriele

Comment: what is the response you are getting can you do a console.log

Comment: @Shankar  It gives me ------> Object { jsonParse=[3]} ----- and on clicking on it I get the below on DOM on the Firebug : -----> [Object { ITEM_CODE=3,  ITEM_NAME="SONY",  ITEM_DESC=" 44 inches",  more...}, Object { ITEM_CODE=4,  ITEM_NAME="GIBSON",  ITEM_DESC="ACOUSTIC ",  more...}, Object { ITEM_CODE=5,  ITEM_NAME="Marvel Avenger",  ITEM_DESC="Captain America ",  more...}]

Comment: what will console.log of response.jsonParse Give

Comment: @Shankar --->  [Object { ITEM_CODE=3,  ITEM_NAME="SONY",  ITEM_DESC=" 44 inches",  more...}, Object { ITEM_CODE=4,  ITEM_NAME="GIBSON",  ITEM_DESC="ACOUSTIC ",  more...}, Object { ITEM_CODE=5,  ITEM_NAME="Marvel Avenger",  ITEM_DESC="Captain America ",  more...}]

Comment: @maverick everything shown so far looks right...create a demo in plunker that reproduces problem. Everyone is simply guessing or getting the properties mixed up

Comment: To my surprise : ::: I just made a little change in HTML ....... I used {{result[0].ITEM_CODE and it printed the whole JSON data on my HTML page. ......... Code change ------> <div class="row" ng-repeat="result in myResult">
   
  
      <p><Strong>Item Name : </Strong>{{result[0].ITEM_CODE}}</p>
      <p><Strong>Item Name : </Strong>{{result.ITEM_NAME}}</p>
----> Output ---->

Item Name :

Item Name : SONY

Item Description : 44 inches

Item Category : TV

Item Code : 3

Item Price : 170

Item Name :

Item Name : GIBSON

Item Description : ACOUSTIC

Comment: @charlietfl :: I wld do that. Thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a real JSON object and not a string as response?

Comment: @GabrieleCiech:  I did this to get the JSON data ::
if(results.length > 0){
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(results);
    var jsonParse = JSON.parse(jsonString);

I hope its JSON.parse() method to get json data from json String.

Comment: @maverick that step is not needed. `$http` has already parsed the json for you and all you are doing is converting to string and right back to the same thing you had before you did this step

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, just observed it while I printed my output on the console. So my query fetched me 3 results and $http parsed the JSON and Output I received on console was ----> Database Results:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] format. And its the same thing which I am getting through Stringify and then parsing it back.